# Сортировка списка в kotlin

Tags: kotlin, list, список

Не совсем понимаю как выполнить сортировку:

У меня есть список из элементов, которые имеют два свойства: **"fileName"** (который является строкой) и **"checkFile**" (который является булевым). С помощью checkFile файлы в списке сортируются на правильные(которые прошли проверку) и неправильные.

**Мне нужно отсортировать список так, чтобы при сортировке файлы, которые не прошли проверку были всегда сверху, а после них правильные**

*Как возможно прописать условие?*

Comment: что вещь такая - список с аргументами?

Comment: список элементов

Comment: чувствую, что мой вопрос не понят :D Отвечать на вопрос "что такое машина с пропеллером" словами "это машина" не только никому не поможет, но и просто глупо. Любой список это список элементов. Что такое список с аргументами? У списка нет и не может быть никаких аргументов.

Comment: @Эникейщик хорошо, спасибо. На будущее учту)Имел ввиду под аргументами то, какие элементы использую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В kotlin есть возможность сортировать коллекции по любому заданному вами принципу с помощью метода `sortBy()`, который принимает на вход лямбду.

Вот пример для вашей ситуации:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(3, 2, 1).withIndex()
    println(list.sortedBy { it.value })
    println(list.sortedBy { it.index })
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!